# Numpy and Pandas concatenation

Tags: pandas, numpy, concatenation

I understand that for Numpy concatenation, the array dimensions must be the same except for the concatenation axis. But for Pandas concatenation, even if the dimensions of the non-concatenation axis are different, it is allowed and will just top up those empty cells as 'NaN'. May I know what is the reason for this difference ?

Numpy concatenation of 2 different arrays along columns

```
s1 = np.arange(3).reshape(3,1) 
s2 = np.arange(2).reshape(2,1)  
result=np.concatenate([s1,s2],axis=1)  
print(result) 

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "example.py", line 8, in <module>
result=np.concatenate([s1,s2],axis=1)
File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 180, in concatenate
ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but        along dimension 0, the array at index 0 has size 3 and the array at index 1 has size 2
```

Pandas concatenation of 2 different Series along columns

```
pd1 = Series([1,2,3])  
pd2 = Series([4,5])  
print(pd1)  
print(pd2)  
result=pd.concat([pd1,pd2],axis=1)  
print(result)

   0    1
0  1  4.0
1  2  5.0
2  3  NaN
```

Comment: They aren't the same function, despite a vague similarity in name.

Comment: Indexing of arrays and Series is different.  `concat` has many more options for joining/merging the Series.  It is possible to write a function that concatenates arrays with some sort of padding, but that's not a common or well defined task in `numpy`.  Note in your example, the 2nd column has switched to `float`, to accommodate the `np.nan` fill.  Did you look at this overview?  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

Comment: `concat` (and `join` and `merge`) implements a lot of the logic of relational databases (SQL).  `concatenate` handles the simplest case where shapes match, and there's no 'missing data'.  You have to use `structured arrays` and `np.lib.recfunctions` to get fancier joins.

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding, `numpy` is built for performing matrix operations very efficiently, and matrix operations require compatible dimensions. In your case, the arrays have different sizes and the concatenation results in a ragged or jagged structure, which is incompatible with `numpy`.

`pandas` is a more general tool for tabulating data, which is often heterogenous in nature with mixed sizes, mixed types, missing values, etc. `pandas` can handle jagged arrays by filling spaces with NaN, as it doesn't assume the data dimensions need to be compatible for matrix operations.